# How to specify index content/entries in Markdown?

Tags: python, markdown, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, myst

Based on the [Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-index), to specify various index entries (`single` entry, for example) in reStructuredText, like this:

```
.. index::
   single: execution; context

The execution context
---------------------
...
```

When using Myst to do the same in Markdown (and according to its [documentation](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.15.1/syntax/syntax.html#directives-a-block-level-extension-point)), this should be its equivalent:

````
```{index}
   single: execution; context
```
````

`sphinx-build` reports an error: `Directive 'index': No content permitted`.

Since adding content to other Sphinx directives (like `toctree`) works, my assumption is there is some hard-coded logic in the `myst_parser` Sphinx extension preventing adding the content for the `index` directive. Is my assumption correct or is there actually a way to add entries to the index in Markdown?

---

**UPDATE**: as per [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75411132/55408), it is possible to put one of the entries directly in the first line, like this:

````
```{index} single: execution; context
```
````

But then the new question is how to add multiple entries into the same index item, which reStructuredText supports (an example from Sphinx docs):

```
.. index::
   single: execution; context
   module: __main__
   module: sys
   triple: module; search; path
```

Comment: Note that there is both a *directive* and a *role* called `index` in ReST. `.. index::` is the directive and `:index:` is the role. The referenced MyST documentation is about roles.

Comment: Yeah, I worded it incorrectly, I meant the directive. Thanks for pointing this out, I will update the question.

Comment: I get a different error message than the one in the question: "Directive 'index': 1 argument(s) required, 0 supplied" (with Sphinx 5.3.0, docutils 0.17.1, myst-parser 0.18.1).

Comment: @mzjn yeah, it's complicated. Try adding a main entry in the first line, like `{index} MainEntry`

Answer (score 1):

Per @mzjn's comment, you probably want the MyST documentation for [Directives - a block-level extension point](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.15.1/syntax/syntax.html#directives-a-block-level-extension-point).

### reStructuredText

```
.. directivename:: arguments
   :key1: val1
   :key2: val2

   This is
   directive content
```

### MyST

````
```{directivename} arguments
---
key1: val1
key2: val2
---
This is
directive content
```
````

For a directive, the arguments are on the same line as the directive, and options are on subsequent lines in key/value pairs. In your example, the MyST directive `index` treats your `single: execution; context` as content, which is not allowed.

Thus try this untested example:

````
```{index} single: execution; context
```
# The execution context
````

### Update

Untested, but try this:

````
```{index}
---
single: execution; context
module: __main__
module: sys
triple: module; search; path
---
```
# The execution context
````

And if that does not work, you could try good old brute force with [`eval-rst`](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/roles-and-directives.html#how-directives-parse-content).

````
```{eval-rst}
.. index::
    single: execution; context
    module: __main__
    module: sys
    triple: module; search; path
```

# The execution context
````

Comment: Thanks! This works for cases when you only need a single entry added to the index, but I still don't know how to add multiple entries (see the updated question) - is there a separator char that can be used in Myst for multiple arguments?

Comment: `eval-rst` is what worked for me.